# TCL - List with Variables

Tags: list, tcl, naming-conventions

I am having trouble creating a list of lists that contains a mixture of text and variables in TCL. I have a user input variable that I then want to plug into a list. I will skip the user select option for brevity.

```
set a 0.1
set b 20.0

set c {
    {text1 text2 $a text3}
    {text4 text5 $b text6}
}

foreach i $c {
    set CheckVal [lindex $i 2]
    puts "Threshold is $CheckVal"
}
```

Resultant output:
Threshold is $a
Threshold is $b

Desired output:
Threshold is 0.1
Threshold is 20.0

Comment: read http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl4.html and http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl14.html -- the examples in those chapters should provide the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two alternatives are

```
set a 0.1
set b 20.0

set c {
    {text1 text2 a text3}
    {text4 text5 b text6}
}

foreach i $c {
    set CheckVal [lindex $i 2]
    puts "Threshold is [set $CheckVal]"
}
```

Store the variable name instead of the value, and get the value by a two-step substitution (`$$Checkval` doesn't work, but `[set $CheckVal]` does) in the `puts` invocation.

```
set a 0.1
set b 20.0

set c {
    {text1 text2 $a text3}
    {text4 text5 $b text6}
}

foreach i $c {
    set CheckVal [lindex $i 2]
    puts [subst "Threshold is $CheckVal"]
}
```

This is double substitution rather than two-step substitution. It looks simple, but `subst` is actually a bit tricky and is almost a last-resort technique.

Regardless of which solution you use, this kind of scheme where you store a reference to a variable value in a structure is fragile since it depends on the original variable being in scope and still existing when the reference is dereferenced. At the very least, you should store a qualified name (namespace and name) in your list. If the variable is a local variable, you need to use it during the same call as when it was stored (or from further up the call stack using `upvar`, but don't go there).

Answer (score 2):

While the methods suggested by Peter Lewerin work, they should only be used as a last resort. Normally you would use some of the commands that operate on lists to create your list of lists. I believe that is what glenn jackman was alluding to.

Depending on your actual code, I would probably use `list` and/or `lappend`:

```
set c {}
lappend c \
  [list text1 text2 $a text3] \
  [list text4 text5 $b text6]
```

Then the foreach will work as you wrote it.